# Deriving the Fourier coefficient equations and notation

Tags: solution-verification, fourier-series, index-notation

I want to start by saying I understand the process of how to obtain equations for $a_n$ and $b_n$ are derived, but there is something about the notation in the derivation that I don't understand.

Lets say $$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(a_n\:cos\left(nx\right)+b_n\:sin\left(nx\right)\right)$$

In the derivation, perhaps of $a_n$, the function is multiplied by $cos(mx)$ and then after simplification we get:
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(a_n\:\delta _{mn}\right)$$

Which gives a formula for $a_m$...
But what I don't get is how we can just replace 'm' with 'n'... If I retry doing the derivation, multiplying $f(x)$ by $cos(nx)$ instead, won't the $a_n$ obtained correspond to the $n$ in the newly multiplied $cos(nx)$, and not the $n$ in the $a_n$ subscript? It is easier to see what I
mean if I use $n_1$ for the coefficient of cos($n_1$x) (in $f(x)$) and $n_2$ inside the argument in the multiplied $cos(nx)$, which gives me
$$\sum _{n_1=1}^{\infty }\left(a_{n_1}\:\delta _{n_1n_2}\right) = a_{n_2}$$ and not a formula for $a_{n_1}$ as I  would have expected from the actual derived equation.

Comment: $\delta_{mn}=1$ iff $m=n$, otherwise its 0, so the only term in the series that survives is when $n=m$, e.g. $a_m$. So you're not replacing $m$ with $n$, rather you're simplifying the sum to its only nonzero term.

Comment: gotcha, i tried replacing m with n and doing the derivation again which led to me getting some sum with $b_n$... only after excluding the other terms did i get what I was looking for. thanks

Comment: after thinking about it some more i am still a little confused. What is n? How can $m = n$ if $n$ varies? I get that the varying n equals m to dimplify to $a_m$, but surely if we want to find $b_n$ and not just $b_m$ we need to set $m$ equal to some $n$.

Comment: How $m$ can equal $n$ when $n$ varies: say for example $m=2$. Now: $n=1: m\ne n$. $n=2: m=n$. $\dots$

Comment: Comment for future reference: Starting with "I want to start by saying I understand the process" doesn't add anything to the math, and it gives an impression that's perhaps not what you'd want to give (because in fact the question is about major misunderstanding of that process. Honest.)

Comment: I just wanted clarification on the notation and didn't want someone to go thorugh deriving it again. I said I understand how the n in the sum equals m in the sigma notation... What I want to know is how m is 'set to' n once the equation for $b_m$ is acheived. Ironically, I don't think you understood my question.

Comment: @GabN.: I think a concrete example may help. Imagine for simplicity you're computing $\sum_{n=0}^2 a_n\delta_{mn}=a_0\delta_{m0}+a_1\delta_{m1}+a_2\delta_{m2}$. The right side is a *function* of $m$. So when you plug in, say, $m=1$, the only term that survives is $a_1$.